# Django NOT displaying SOME images on webpage

Tags: django

I am creating an app which is having categories of workers. So I hv created model for getting worker data and using that data I am displaying it on webpage. but when I want to display worker data of specific category Django showing some images on page, NOT ALL.

[here is my models.py:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7YCa.png)

[settings.py:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH3eO.png)

[urls.py:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFkPK.png)

[views.py : In views.py I have created to funtions (display()-It is used for displaying all worker data and its displaying all images also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ36a.png)

[display.html: for showing all worker data on a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB5Cj.png)
[Here is the one data  along  with image (output of display.html)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7cZb.png)

Now coming to point as I said above that django is not displaying some images on page for specific category(checkout views.py in which category is Painter())

[here is Painter.html:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqm1B.png)

[Here is the output of Painter.html: Notice that on this page the card which is not showing Image works fine on DISPLAY.HTML but not on PAINTER.HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YsyY.png)

NOTE : I used ({{i.myfile}}) in painter.html because of that it is showing some images and not showing other image.
In display.html I have used {{dest.myfile.url}} which works fine there and shows all images.
But when i used {{i.myfile.url}} in painter.html. Its not showing any image at all

I dont know whats going wrong but why it is not showing some images and showing some images on PAINTER.HTML
Note: all images have same extension!
Please help!

Comment: Hello, paste your code as text instead of screenshots. Read this help section about formatting code in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: thanks for reply. I have solved error.

Comment: [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is worth reading before posting